# GeoServer - GetFeatureInfo GeoJSON - different precision in different workspaces

Tags: geoserver, geojson, getfeatureinfo

I've just set up my GeoServer and app to work with `application/json` GetFeatureInfo requests.  One of the advantages of this is that it returns the feature in GeoJSON format along with the attributes.  This allows me to "highlight" the feature which currently has a popup open.  I have two of the exact same datasets in different GeoServer workspaces.  When clicking on the exact same feature one workspace returns a very coarse GeoJSON (about 10 vertices) while the other returns a detailed GeoJSON (over 100 vertices).  The coarse version is fine when zoomed out but if you zoom in after clicking a feature you see a very simplified and inaccurate highlighted feature.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?  To my knowledge I have no workspace specific settings and am using global settings for everything in my GeoServer.

Comment: Is the datastore PostGIS and could there be a difference with on-the-fly simplification being on or off? You told you have not changed the defaults but check anyway.

Comment: That did the trick! I wasn't aware of this setting and I don't know when I would have checked/unchecked it but it was on for the 'problem' workspace.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Support on the fly geometry simplification" was checked on for the problem data store.  Unchecking it resolved this issue.

[image: On-the-fly simplification setting]